# Options for setting mandatory fields on components created by code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, encapsulation

When I create a `GameObject` like below I want my component to have/set mandatory fields.

```
GameObject go = new GameObject("MyGameObject");
MyComponent myComponent = go.addComponent(MyComponent);
```

Since I cannot use a constructor to set private fields I either need a setter for these fields or a public `Init` function that sets multiple mandatory properties. But this allows changing the values anywhere in the code and unlike a constructor with overloads it's not obvious that `Init` "needs to" or "can be" called after creation to set these parameters.

So are there other options that allow me to set mandatory fields when creating a Component and use "proper" encapsulation?

Comment: please add the code of `MyComponent`. You also probably ment either `go.addComponent(typeof(MyComponent)) as MyComponent` or `go.addComponent<MyComponent>()`, right? Overall it sounds like the [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) method already has exactly that purpose, hasn't it?

Comment: The code could just be a private string field that can be set in the constructor which outputs the value each update to the console. Since it is private I can only set it in constructor and that is what I want so it is encapsulated and only changed when I initially add this component to a `GameObject`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as stated in the comments, Unity implemented 2 main methods for MonoBehaviour initialization logic: [Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html).

There are drawbacks of these 2 initialization methods:

- They cannot accept any parameter
- You're not sure of their order of execution

There's a standard [order of execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) and from this you can be sure that Start is executed after Awake. But if you have multiple MonoBehaviours of the same type then it's not easy to track which executes first.

If your issue is just the execution order and you have have different types then you could just update the [script execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).

Otherwise there are further approaches to avoid both drawbacks by using a Factory Method inside the monobehaviour.

Consider that in this case the order of execution will be:
**Awake** => OnEnable => Reset => **Start** => **YOUR INIT METHOD**

### PRIVATE FACTORY METHOD

```cs
public class YourMono : MonoBehaviour
{
    //a factory method with the related gameobject and the init parameters
    public static YourMono AddWithInit(GameObject target, int yourInt, bool yourBool)
    {
        var yourMono = target.AddComponent<YourMono>();
        yourMono.InitMonoBehaviour(yourInt, yourBool);
        return yourMono;
    }

    private void InitMonoBehaviour(int yourInt, bool yourBool)
    {
        //init here
    }
}
```

This method offers the better encapsulation since we can be sure that **InitMonoBehaviour** wioll be called just once.

### EXTENSION FACTORY

You can also create a factory from an extension. In this case you remove the factory method from the class, it might be useful to decouple factory logic from gameplay logic.

But in this case you will need to make **InitMonoBehaviour** internal and implement the extension in the same namespace.
As a result InitMonoBehaviour will be a bit more accessible (internally from the same namespace) so it has lower encapsulation.

```cs
    [Serializable]
    public class YourData
    {
    }

    namespace YourMonoNameSpace.MonoBehaviourFactory
    {
        public static class MonoFactory
        {
            public static YourMono AddYourMono(this GameObject targetObject, YourData initData)
            {
                var yourMono = targetObject.AddComponent<YourMono>();
                yourMono.InitMonoBehaviour(initData);
                return yourMono;
            }
        }
    }

    namespace YourMonoNameSpace
    {
        public class YourMono : MonoBehaviour
        {
            private YourData _componentData= null;
            internal void InitMonoBehaviour(YourData initData)
            {
                if(_componentData !=  null ) return;
                _componentData = initData;
            }
        }
    }
```

That said both of these options has also a drawback:

- Someone could forget to launch them.

So, if you want this method to be "required" and not optional, I suggest to add a bool flag _isInitiated to make sure no one forgot to implement it.

### INVERSION OF CONTROL - INSIDE AWAKE

Personally I would implement the logic with an [Scriptable Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html), or with a [Singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton), and I would call it during awake to make sure the initialization is called all the times.

```cs
public class YourMonoAutoInit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InitLogic _initializationLogic;

    //a factory method with the related gameobject and the init parameters
    public void Awake()
    {
        //make sure we not miss initialization logic
        Assert.IsNotNull(_initializationLogic);
        InitMonoBehaviour(_initializationLogic);

    }

    private void InitMonoBehaviour(InitLogic initializationLogic)
    {
        //init here using
        int request = initializationLogic.currentRequest;
        bool playerAlive = initializationLogic.playerIsAlive;
    }
}

public class InitLogic : ScriptableObject
{
    public int currentRequest = 1;
    public bool playerIsAlive = false;
}

//this is another monobehaviour that might access the player state and change it
public class KillPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InitLogic playerState;
    public void KillThisPlayer() => playerState.playerIsAlive = false;
}
```

With this last version you're achieving inversion of control.
So instead of SETTING DATA INTO THE MONOBEHAVIOUR:

```cs
//SETTING DATA FROM CLASS TO MONOBEHAVIOUR
public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void CreateMonoBehaviour() => YourMono.AddWithInit(gameObject, 1, true);
}
```

You will GET DATA IN MONOBEHVARIOUS FROM CLASS.

```cs
//GETTING IN MONOBEHVARIOUS FROM CLASS
public class YourOtherMono : MonoBehaviour
{
    public YourData data;

    private void Awake()
    {
        (int yourInt, bool yourBool) = data.GetData();
        //do something with the data received
    }
}
```

Comment: to `it's not easy to track which executes first.` it can easely be configured using the [`Script Execution Order`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)

Comment: @derHugo that works, but not in this case for Start and Awake. If you have 100 MonoBehaviour with 100 Awake methods you cannot set which one to launch first. They are controlled by the hierarchy, yes, but this mean the hiearchy would become too rigid.

Comment: if they are all of the same type than you are right ... but if it is 100 different MonoBehaviours than yes you can controll the order

Comment: Yes. I see this question about "how to add parameters" more than "how to solve the execution order", but I agree it's worth a mention. Thanks for the note @derHugo.

Comment: Thanks you for this very thorough answer.