# Cant find object collection when trying to get collection by FindObjectByType

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to find all objects by type of `Tiledata`.

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
  using UnityEngine.UI;
  using System.Linq; 

  ....

  Tiledata Test1 = new Tiledata(3, 1);
  Debug.Log(Test1.growTime);
  foreach(Tiledata Tile in FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<Tiledata>()) {
      Debug.Log("Test");
  }
```

Class:

```
public class Tiledata
 {
     public int growTime;
     public int growLevel;

     public Tiledata(int growTime1, int growLevel1) {
        growTime = growTime1;
        growLevel = growLevel1;
     }

 }
```

I get NO errors in my code.

If I debug the `Test1.growTime`, i sure enough get 3. so the `Test1` can be referenced.

But my problem is when I have many Tiledata, and I would like to iterate trough them. In my foreach I try and iterate trough them, but nothing comes up.

No code is executed within for foreach loop, so seems like there is no object of type `Tiledata`, even though I can reference it, and it is created right above the foreach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>()` finds the `MonoBehaviour`, or better, a [Unity.Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) in the scene. More info in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html).

> It will return no assets (meshes, textures, prefabs, ...) or inactive
>   objects. Will not return objects that have HideFlags.DontSave set. Use
>   Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll to avoid these limitations.

`Tiledata` does not derive from `MonoBehaviour`, so it won't be found.

To find it (with `FindObjectsOfType`) you need to derive it from `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class Tiledata : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int growTime;
     public int growLevel;

     public Tiledata(int growTime1, int growLevel1) {
        growTime = growTime1;
        growLevel = growLevel1;
     }

 }
```

And to add it in the game as a `Component` (that requires also a `GameObject` to be attached to).

```
Tiledata Test1 = new GameObject().AddComponent<Tiledata>();
  Debug.Log(Test1.growTime);
  foreach(Tiledata Tile in FindObjectsOfType<Tiledata>()) {
      Debug.Log("Test");
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jack, yep this does the trick. I have a followup: how would I set growTime and growLevel on creation of the object (and not have to assign each values manually, e.g. Test1.name = "name")?

Comment: You could use [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html). Or create a public method `SetupTile(int time, int level) => (growTime, growLevel)  => (time, level);`. For advanced behaviour you may follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218963/options-for-setting-mandatory-fields-on-components-created-by-code/56220929#56220929). If you require further details it would be better to ask that in another question.